# How to query or insert a value into a binary(1) field in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, binary, sql-server-2012

I've tried googling for a while and couldn't find anything, but apologies if this is really obvious.

I have a Boolean array that is always length 8 and I want to insert the corresponding binary value into a `binary(1)` field. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Currently I convert it into a string, e.g `"10100101"`, and create a query string that looks something like `"INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('10100101');"` Also have been trying to get a `SELECT` statement equivalent `"SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE bin_val=10100101;"`

When I execute the statement I always get a syntax error. I've tried multiple variations (e.g with/without quote marks etc and putting the number in different format e.g `"0xA5"`) with no luck.

Any suggestions?

p.s Writing code in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will need to convert your binary based number to a decimal based one. Then, you can simply convert that value to the datatype `BINARY`. So, assuming that your string is always 8 bits long, you can try this:

```
DECLARE @BinaryNumber CHAR(8)
SET @BinaryNumber = '10100101'
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT  CAST(SUBSTRING(@BinaryNumber,8,1)+
             SUBSTRING(@BinaryNumber,7,1)*2+
             SUBSTRING(@BinaryNumber,6,1)*4+
             SUBSTRING(@BinaryNumber,5,1)*8+
             SUBSTRING(@BinaryNumber,4,1)*16+
             SUBSTRING(@BinaryNumber,3,1)*32+
             SUBSTRING(@BinaryNumber,2,1)*64+
             SUBSTRING(@BinaryNumber,1,1)*128 AS BINARY(1))
```

Comment: thanks! Got it to work for INSERT INTO statement.
However can't get it to for  the SELECT statement... my statement is this:

"SELECT * FROM CASES WHERE bin_val=CAST(3 AS BINARY(1))"

It says: Incorrect syntax near '='

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked on SQL Server but I think you need to something like

```
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES( CAST(10100101  AS BINARY(1)) );
```

More info here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx

Comment: op needs to first convert `10100101` to a decimal based value